# require can't find gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem that I created and pushed to rubygems. I proceeded to download that gem to test some other parts of the related program I'm writing, but Ruby cannot seem to find the gem. When I ask for the path to the gem, called `rbtex`, I get the following (expected) output:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbtex-0.1.0
```

and when I ask for another gem, colorize, that I know is working, I get

```
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/colorize-0.7.7
```

If I open `irb` I can require the colorize gem, but not the rbtex gem:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rbtex'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rbtex
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from (irb):1
from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> require 'colorize'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
```

I'm not sure why one gem works fine but the other does not. I'm running OS X El Captain, and I used `sudo` to download both gems.